# System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null, Parameter name: implementationInstance

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

I deployed .NET core mvc application in IIS, when I run app, the page show 502.5 error, I run command in powershell "dotnet D:\deploy\WebApp\WebApp.dll" ,this follow show detail error content:

**NOTE:**.net core version 2.0.0

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Parameter name: implementationInstance

at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions
.AddSingleton[TService](IServiceCollection services, TService implementationInstance)
```

I know how the error occurred, how to instantiate?

```
public class Startup
{   ...
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddSingleton(CreateQuery());  // this is error location
        ...
    }

    IQuery CreateQuery()
    {
        IQuery query = null;
        var dataBase = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")["DataBase"];
        var defaultConnection = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["SqlServer"];
        switch (dataBase)
        {
            case "sqlserver":
                query = new WebApp.Query.Query(defaultConnection);
                break;
        }
        return query;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you instanced implementationInstance before you use it?

Comment: has been instantiated, but this may not work

Comment: remove the TService before the implementationInstance..

Comment: I do not know. Net core how to new a instance injection, may not, I have changed the usual dependency injection, and now the program can run, thank you for your help

Comment: @Lin.Hao Please update the solution

Answer (score 2):

In case someone comes along looking for a possible solution, I was able to resolve this issue in a .NET Core 3.1 project by getting the configuration using the `IServiceProvider` callback provided by `.AddSingleton` in the following way:

```
public class Startup
{   ...
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        // Pass the service provider that AddSingleton provides
        services.AddSingleton((serviceProvider) => {
            CreateQuery(serviceProvider)
        });
        ...
    }

    IQuery CreateQuery(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IQuery query = null;

        // Use the service provider to get the configuration
        var configuration = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

        var dataBase = configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")["DataBase"];
        var defaultConnection = configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["SqlServer"];
        switch (dataBase)
        {
            case "sqlserver":
                query = new WebApp.Query.Query(defaultConnection);
                break;
        }
        return query;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, make sure the instance passed into `services.AddSingleton` is not null. For me this error was thorwn because of an error in the code resulted in returning null object from the function.