# AppSettings not getting resolved via constructor injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, appsettings

I have the configuration in `appsettings.json` as follows:

```
{
"Logging": {
"IncludeScopes": false,
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Warning"
}
},
 "GatewaySettings": {
 "DBName": "StorageDb.sqlite",
 "DBSize": "100"    
 }
}
```

Here is the class to represent the configuration data

```
 public class GatewaySettings
 {
    public string DBName { get; set; }
    public string DBSize { get; set; }
 }
```

Configured service as follows:

```
  services.AddSingleton(Configuration.GetSection("GatewaySettings").Get<GatewaySettings>());
```

but I'm getting this error:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: implementationInstance'

Code:

```
  public class SqlRepository
  {
        private readonly GatewaySettings _myConfiguration;

        public SqlRepository(GatewaySettings settings)
        {
              _myConfiguration = settings;
        }
  }
```

Dependency injection code:

```
var settings = new IOTGatewaySettings();
builder.Register(c => new SqlRepository(settings))
```

**Background**

I am hosting ASPNET CORE application as windows service, and .NET Framework is 4.6.1

Note: similar question appears here but there is no solution provided.[System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null, Parameter name: implementationInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47917030/system-argumentnullexception-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-implementati)

Comment: Use `IOptions<T>` instead Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't add concrete data model classes into DI - use the [`IOptions<>` framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration).

In your startup:

```
services.AddOptions();

// parses the config section into your data model
services.Configure<GatewaySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("GatewaySettings"));
```

Now, in your class:

```
public class SqlRepository
{
    private readonly GatewaySettings _myConfiguration;
    public SqlRepository(IOptions<GatewaySettings> gatewayOptions)
    {
        _myConfiguration = gatewayOptions.Value;
        // optional null check here
    }
}
```

Note: if your project does not include the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` package, you will need to add another package `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions` to get this functionality.

Comment: I am getting this error  Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0 is not compatible with net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0 supports: netcoreapp2.1 while adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.All

Comment: What version of .Net Core are you using? Why are you using .Net 4.6.1?

Comment: Yes, I am using 4.6.1

Comment: Resolved. I suppose to add Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions in .net standard project

Comment: quick question: Now how do I register in SqlRepository in autofac?  do I have to use aspnet core built in dependency injection?

Comment: Autofac, no idea. But I can answer other questions related to Microsoft's DI. Follow me into [this chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68414/socvr-testing-facility) so we don't clog up the comments section if you don't mind.

Comment: @codetoshare AutoFac has extension to plug into core DI. check their documentation for more details.

Comment: @codetoshare it is actually also in MS documentation as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#replacing-the-default-services-container

Comment: Is IOptions is only for .net core?

Comment: But how to call the parameterized contructor from outside class?\

Answer (score 3):

You should use IOptions of T

```
services.Configure<GatewaySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("GatewaySettings"));

  public class SqlRepository
  {
    private readonly GatewaySettings _myConfiguration;
    public SqlRepository(IOptions<GatewaySettings> settingsAccessor)
    {
          _myConfiguration = settingsAccessor.Value;
    }
  }
```

you need these packages

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="2.1.0" />
```

Reference [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: What references we need to add to get IOptions? This is asp.net core application running as windows service